# How to add a button inside message body in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have tried constructing message body like below-

i am getting object object exception and it isn't working for me if i keep inside message body-

```
      "Dear " +
      $scope.emailContactinfo.name +
      ", \n\nPlease find attached Invoice bearing number " +
      $scope.invoiceInformation.documentNo +"Paynow\n\n" +$scope.generatedUrl + 
      " dated " + 
      moment($scope.invoiceInformation.invoiceDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY") +
      ". \n\nThanks and Regards,\n" +
      $scope.invoiceInformation.organization$_identifier +
      "." + button ;`
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using this format, so the code is more readable -

```
 const button = '<button>Button</button>';
`Dear ${$scope.emailContactinfo.name}, \n\nPlease find attached Invoice bearing number ${$scope.invoiceInformation.documentNo} Paynow\n\n ${$scope.generatedUrl} dated ${ moment($scope.invoiceInformation.invoiceDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}. \n\nThanks and Regards,\n ${$scope.invoiceInformation.organization$_identifier}. ${button}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use html in a javascript variable like this e.g.:

```
var button = '<button>Button</button>';
var htmlBody = '<div>' + $scope.emailContactInfo + '</div>;
htmlBody += '<div>' + button + '</div>';
```